# RedHat 6.2 - Find the right place to download packages (RPM)

Tags: redhat, rpm, rhel6

During a server install a custom script required the specific packages missing in my server:

•   sssd.x86_64
•   sssd-client.x86_64
•   cyrus-sasl-gssapi.x86_64
•   c-ares.x86_64
•   libtdb.x86_64
•   libldb.x86_64
•   libini_config.x86_64
•   libdhash.x86_64
•   libcollection.x86_64
•   libtevent.x86_64
•   openldap-clients.x86_64
•   autofs.x86_64

In the internet i can find the packages but for CentOs or not even find them.
Is there a reference place to find Redhat RPMs?

Comment: You need to activate your RHEL subscription before installing third party packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register the box with red hat network using the subscription-manager command, which will grant access to the rhel repos. If for some reason you need RHEL6.2 explicitly then you can associate your server with those repos in the subscription management tab of rhn.redhat.com. By default you'll get the latest available packages, but why this would be undesireable is beyond me, especially for SSSD which I have encountered a lot of bugs in the older versions of.

Or you could mount the RHEL 6.2 DVD which contains those packages.